Why is this timing function getting a typeError?
The timer stops when the mouse hovers over a (.typing) item and the timer resumes when the mouse leaves. That works, but I wanted to remove two classes from separate id's when their respective setTimeout function hits 0.
Heres the code:
let dhaTimeout = {
  id: null,
  startTime: 0,
  remainingTime: 5000,
  isPaused: false
}
let stackTimeout = {
  id: null,
  startTime: 0,
  remainingTime: 10000,
  isPaused: false
}

function startTimeout(timeout, elementId){
  if(timeout.isPaused){
    timeout.isPaused = false;
    timeout.startTime = Date.now();
    timeout.id = setTimeout(() => {
      const element = document.getElementById(elementId)
      if(element){
        element.classList.remove("gone")  
      } else { 
        console.log(`Element not found, ${elementId}`)
      }
    }, timeout.remainingTime)
  } else{
      timeout.startTime = Date.now()
      timeout.id = setTimeout(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById(elementId)
        element.classList.remove("gone")}, timeout.remainingTime)
    }
  }
function pauseTimeout(timeout){
  if(!timeout.isPaused && timeout.id){
    clearTimeout(timeout.id)
    timeout.isPaused = true;
    timeout.remainingTime = timeout.remainingTime - (Date.now() - timeout.startTime)
    timeout.id = null
  }
}

function onMouseEnter(){
  pauseTimeout(stackTimeout)
  pauseTimeout(dhaTimeout)
}

function onMouseLeave(){
  startTimeout(stackTimeout)
  startTimeout(dhaTimeout)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".typing").forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter)
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave)
  })
})

startTimeout(stackTimeout, 'full-stack')
startTimeout(dhaTimeout, 'dha')



I'm getting a typeError when the startTimeout function is called for the second time, saying can't read classList when it's null. So I logged the element to see if its there but its not finding it.. but I have nothing removing the individual element so it's not making sense to me how it's not finding the element, maybe the class but the element being gone? I didn't think the html code was necessary as its 3 p elements, first two with the 'typing' class and last two with the 'gone' class. id of 'dha' for the second p and 'full-stack' for the third.
I've tried to add a separate if else for the failure of finding the element to find it again somehow but that lead nowhere.

What is the exact error message?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

The error almost certainly is saying that element is null. Which means that document.getElementById(elementId) couldn't find the ID.
